# How to perform pagination with Mandrill's search results

Tags: email, search

I'm working with Mandrill's API Messages->Search and am having trouble figuring out how to develop pagination into my client.

I notice that the limit of a result return is 1000 messages returned, and there is a 20 call per minute throttle, but when I have mail campaigns greater than 1000 messages I would like to paginate through the results.

https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=search

I've noticed I can grab entire result sets through the Exports->Activity method but this method does not provide meta searches, and also does not return readable data for my client.

https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/exports.JSON.html#method=activity

The next option would be to use Webhooks but clients will be hosted on a range of different servers, some shared, some dedicated, and for large email campaigns  with 5000+ sent messages the callbacks might harm server performance.

https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/webhooks.JSON.html

So the best solution would be to paginate & cache the results of the Messages->Search method.

Comment: Hi, have you been in touch with them to see if there is something you can do?

Comment: Not since their recent announcement that they will be absorbed into MailChimp for MC users only and the pricing triples. 

I'm currently researching alternatives to Mandrill.